# Sumifs type summary in Crystal report vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports, summary, sumifs

I have a table in access database named received. Following is the example data to explain my question:-

Product A   20
Product B   35

Product C   40

Product A   10

Product B   20

Product C   25

I need a summary in Crystal report as given below:

Product A   30

Product B   55

Product C   65

I went through all platforms on internet but could not find the answer. If any can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a table as your data source, you should use a query built within Access.

- Create a new query, and add the table.
- Add the ProductName and ProductQty fields to the query grid.
- Click on the "Totals" button on the Query Design menubar, which adds a new row to the query grid captioned "Total".
- Change the "Group By" under the ProductQty field in the query grid to "Sum".

When you run the query, you should the required output, which can then be used.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to know that can it be calculated with date criteria as well. Another thing comes in my mind how it is done with SQL database if there is no sumifs type option in vb.net. I am really surprised that no such function in vb.net because absence of this function reporting in vb.net is quite incomplete.

Comment: Please modify your question to show your original data including the date, and also how you expect the output to look, based on the date criteria that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this in Crystal.
The simplest is to insert a CrossTab with Product Name as Row and Quantity as Value to be summed.